# Understanding this clamp network

Tags: bjt, flyback, diode-clamp

The circuit below is from this [Reference Design](http://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-00628).

I want to understand the clamp network at the input. How is VGS of Q1 kept at a safe level?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

L2 may allow enough dv/dt at the source to keep the Vgs of [Q1](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/FQPF2N80-111857.pdf) safe. There certainly isn't sufficient current to charge C3 fast enough in a worst-case situation.

Looks pretty janky to me, but maybe it's okay.